# How to hide Bootstrap modal with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I've read the posts here, the Bootstrap site, and Googled like mad - but can't find what I'm sure is an easy answer...

I have a Bootstrap modal that I open from a link_to helper like this:

```
<%= link_to "New Contact", new_contact_path, {remote: true, 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => "#myModal",  class: "btn btn-primary"} %>
```

In my `ContactsController.create` action, I have code that creates `Contact` then passes off to `create.js.erb`. In `create.js.erb`, I have some error handling code (a mix of ruby and javascript). If everything goes well, I want to close the modal.

This is where I'm having trouble. I can't seem to dismiss the modal when all goes well.

I've tried `$('#myModal').modal('hide');` and this has no effect. I've also tried `$('#myModal').hide();` which causes the modal to dismiss but leaves the backdrop.

Any guidance on how to close the modal and/or dismiss the backdrop from within `create.js.erb`?

**Edit**

Here's the markup for myModal:

```
<div class="modal hide" id="myModal" >
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
    <h3>Add Contact</h3>
    <div id="errors_notification">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= form_for :contact, url: contacts_path, remote: true do |f| %>  
      <%= f.text_field :first_name, placeholder: "first name" %>
      <%= f.text_field :last_name, placeholder: "last name" %>
      <br>
      <%= f.submit "Save", name: 'save', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <a class="close btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#myModal').modal('hide');` is the correct syntax to close/hide the modal with id `myModal` (you can test this on the [Bootstrap documentation page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)). Are you sure you have an element with this id on your page? Also, what are you trying to accomplish with this call? Your current implementation performs an Ajax request to `new_contact_path` and at the same time opens the modal with the contents of `#myModal` – is this what you want?

Comment: Hi, Julian. I posted myModal markup above and there is, indeed, a div with id `myModal`. I re-tried `$('myModal').modal('hide')` and still no good. HM.

In terms of what I'm trying to accomplish, I think it may have been incorrect to use the link_to helper. I've replaced this with: `<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary">Add Contact</a>` since I don't really need a call to `new_contact_path`. I just want the modal to open and then deal with user input.

Thanks for taking the time to respond. I'll see if I can't sort this out.

Comment: I guess it's just a typo, but the call should be `$('#myModal').modal('hide');`(there is an `#` missing in your comment).

Comment: My bad for typing instead of copying from actual code. The actual code reads: `$('#myModal').modal('hide')`. J

Comment: You can try using bootboxjs

Comment: Minor comment here, but in your markup, your #myModal element already has the class '.hide' in it? Applying that class to that element by hand would cause the modal closing behavior to be erratic (e.g. the modal box would hide, but not the gray overlay behind it). Just a thought.

Answer (score 591):

With the modal open in the browser window, use the browser's console to try

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

If it works (and the modal closes) then you know that your close Javascript is *not* being sent from the server to the browser correctly.

If it doesn't work then you need to investigate further on the client what is happening. Eg make sure that there aren't two elements with the same id. Eg does it work the first time after page load but not the second time?

Browser's console: firebug for firefox, the debugging console for Chrome or Safari, etc.

Comment: The second paragraph was what I was looking for. Duplicate ID's were making my modals not to show correctly the second time.

Comment: Please mentioned the bootstrap version here. it will dot work on current bootstrap

Comment: Different versions of Bootstrap e.g. 4.6.1 and 5.0.1 was loaded on same page in my case, that is why modal hiding did not worked!

Answer (score 88):

to close bootstrap [**modal**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) you can pass **'hide'** as option to modal method as follow

```
$('#modal').modal('hide');
```

Please take a look at working **[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/subodhghulaxe/MGbXk/)**

bootstrap also provide events that you can hook into [modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) functionality, like if you want to fire a event when the modal has finished being hidden from the user you can use **hidden.bs.modal** event you can read more about modal methods and events here in **[Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)**

If non of the above method work, give a id to your close button and trigger click on close button.

Comment: This is especially useful when you know exactly at what point the modal dialog is supposed to close. For example at the end of a success function.  That way if there is an error, the dialog can display it.

Answer (score 68):

The Best form to hide and show a modal with bootstrap it's

```
// SHOW
$('#ModalForm').modal('show');
// HIDE
$('#ModalForm').modal('hide');
```

Comment: Best answer by far. Simulating behavior with clicks, jQuery fadeOut or css can create misalignments in the long run.

Answer (score 59):

I use Bootstrap 3.4
For me this does not work

`$('#myModal').modal('hide')`

In desperation,I did this:

```
$('#myModal').hide();
$('.modal-backdrop').hide();
```

Maybe it's not elegant, but it works

Comment: It would be better if you use $(".modal-backdrop").remove();

Comment: this will introduce new bugs. please use recommend methods,

Comment: jQuery('.modal-backdrop').click();

Comment: little buggy but surely works.  **Manuel Fernando**'s solution below worked perfectly for me.

Comment: @Umingo please recommend a method if the ones mentioned here are no good and you know of one.

Comment: Thanks @Gaza, in times of desperation we need heroes like you.

Answer (score 49):

I was experiencing with that same error and this line of code really helps me.

```
$("[data-dismiss=modal]").trigger({ type: "click" });
```

Comment: I've read another issue that suggested the problem could be having the data-dismiss attribute on the element, then on top of this attempting to trigger it from javascript

Comment: Many Many Many thanks Manuel, this after a lot of search solved my problem,                   $('#MyModelId').modal('hide');
$("[data-dismiss=modal]").trigger({ type: "click" });    that i wanted to close the modal on ajax success .... really many thanks my dear

Answer (score 30):

I found the correct solution you can use this code

```
$('.close').click();
```

Comment: best solution so far

Comment: superb simply is the best +1

Answer (score 30):

```
$('#modal').modal('hide'); 
//hide the modal

$('body').removeClass('modal-open'); 
//modal-open class is added on body so it has to be removed

$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
//need to remove div with modal-backdrop class
```

Comment: it worked, but broke down modal if I open it again modal doesn't scroll anymore

Answer (score 11):

I ran into what I believe was a similar issue.  The `$('#myModal').modal('hide');` is likely running through that function and hits the line

```
if (!this.isShown || e.isDefaultPrevented()) return
```

The issue is that the value isShown may be undefined even if the modal is displayed and the value should be true.  I've modified the bootstrap code slightly to the following

```
if (!(typeof this.isShown == 'undefined') && (!this.isShown || e.isDefaultPrevented())) return
```

This seemed to resolve the issue for the most part.  If the backdrop still remains you could always add a call to manually remove it after the hide call `$('.modal-backdrop').remove();`.  Not ideal at all but does work.

Answer (score 11):

(Referring to Bootstrap 3), To hide the modal use: `$('#modal').modal('hide')`. But the reason the backdrop hung around (for me) was because I was destroying the DOM for the modal before 'hide' finished.

To resolve this, I chained the hidden event with the DOM removal. In my case: `this.render()`

```
var $modal = $('#modal');

//when hidden
$modal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) { 
  return this.render(); //DOM destroyer
});

$modal.modal('hide'); //start hiding
```

Comment: but can you please tell me about `this.render()` its showing `undefined is not a function` in my chrome console.

Answer (score 10):

I had better luck making the call after the "shown" callback occurred:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
      $('#myModal').modal('hide');
})
```

This ensured the modal was done loading before the hide() call was made.

Answer (score 10):

What we found was that there was just a slight delay between the call to our server code and the return to the success call back.  If we wrapped the call to the server in the `$("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e)` handler and then called the `$("#myModal").modal("hide");` method, the browser would hide the modal and then invoke the server side code.

Again, not elegant but functional.

```
 function myFunc(){
        $("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
            // Invoke your server side code here.
        });
        $("#myModal").modal("hide");
 };
```

As you can see, when `myFunc` is invoked, it will hide the modal and then invoke the server side code.

Answer (score 10):

Hiding modal backdrop works but then any subsequent opening of the modal and the backdrop doesn't hide like it should.  I found this works consistently:

```
// SHOW
$('#myModal').modal('show')
$('.modal-backdrop').show();

// HIDE
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
$('.modal-backdrop').hide();
```

Answer (score 8):

I used this simple code:

```
$("#MyModal .close").click();
```

Answer (score 6):

I was experiencing the same problem, and after a bit of experimentation I found a solution. In my click handler, I needed to stop the event from bubbling up, like so:

```
$("a.close").on("click", function(e){
  $("#modal").modal("hide");
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is the doc:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods

Here is the method:
    $('#myModal').modal('hide')

If you need to open several times the modal with different content, I suggest to add (in you main js):

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
      $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });
```

So you will clean the content for the next opening and avoid a kind of caching

Answer (score 6):

```
$('.modal-backdrop').hide(); // for black background
$('body').removeClass('modal-open'); // For scroll run
$('#modal').modal('hide');
```

Answer (score 6):

Even I have the same kind of issues. This helped me a lot

```
$("[data-dismiss=modal]").trigger({ type: "click" });
```

Answer (score 6):

`$('#modal').modal('hide');` and its variants did not work for me unless I had `data-dismiss="modal"` as an attribute on the Cancel button. Like you, my needs were to possibly close / possibly-not close based on some additional logic so clicking a link with `data-dismiss="modal"` outright would not do. I ended up having a hidden button with `data-dismiss="modal"` that I could programmatically invoke the click handler from, so

```
<a id="hidden-cancel" class="hide" data-dismiss="modal"></a>
<a class="close btn">Cancel</a>
```

and then inside the click handlers for cancel when you need to close the modal you can have

```
$('#hidden-cancel').click();
```

Comment: In my case (asp net razor page) I had it similiar to the OP: i had an somewhat empty div with class "modal" and dynamically added a cshtml file to it, e.g. the modal body and added a click to a button of this body as soon as the modal would be shown. calling ".modal('hide)" alone was not sufficient, as you pointed out: "data-dismiss="modal"" on the invoking button was the deal!!! ty

Answer (score 5):

In my case I was apparently trying to close the dialog too fast after showing it.  So in my close modal function I used this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    $('#loadingModal').modal('hide');
}, 300);
```

Answer (score 3):

We need to take care of event bubbling. Need to add one line of code

```
$("#savechanges").on("click", function (e) {
        $("#userModal").modal("hide");
        e.stopPropagation(); //This line would take care of it
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old question, but I found that none of these were really what I was looking for exactly. It seems to be caused by trying to close the modal before it's finished showing.

My solution was based on @schoonie23's answer but I had to change a few things.

First, I declared a global variable at the top of my script:

```
<script>
    var closeModal = false;
    ...Other Code...
```

Then in my modal code:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    ...Some Code...
    if (someReasonToHideModal) {
        closeModal = true;
        return;
    }
    ...Other Code...
```

Then this: (Note the name 'shown.bs.modal' indicating that the modal has shown completely as opposed to 'show' that triggers when the show event is called. (I originally tried just 'shown' but it did not work.)

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
    if (closeEditModal) {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        closeModal = false;
    }
});
```

Hope this saves someone the extra research some day. I spent a bit looking for a solution before I came up with this.

Answer (score 2):

document.getElementById('closeButton').click(); // add a data-dismiss="modal" attribute to an element in the modal and give it this id

Answer (score 1):

I used this code -

Hide modal with smooth effect using Fade Out.

```
$('#myModal').fadeOut();

$('.modal-backdrop').fadeOut();

$('.modal-open').css({'overflow': 'visible'});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar problem where my custom modal would show via js but I could not hide it (there was no close button).

For me the solution was to add the content into a `modal-dialog`.

```html
<div class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="loading">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    loading
  </div>
</div>
```

Without the `modal-dialog` it would happily show the modal, but it was impossible to hide it without the manual solutions in some of the answers here, some of which prevent you then being able to show the modal again.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the close class in your modals, the following will work. Depending on your use case, I generally recommend filtering to only the visible modal if there are more than one modals with the close class.

```
$('.close:visible').click();
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the bad practice but you can use this technique to close modal by calling close button in javascript.
This will close modal after 3 seconds.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
window.onload=function()
{
setInterval(function(){ 

$("#closemodal").click();
}, 3000);

}
</script> 
</head>
<body>

   <div class="container">
 <h2>Modal Example</h2>
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal"   data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="closemodal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>

 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Some times

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
$('#myModal').hide();
```

does not get the job done so you need to add this to footer of your modal:

```
<button type="button" id="close_cred_modal" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

and than add this line to close the modal

```
$('#close_cred_modal').click();
```