# Event to wait for dialog to disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

In a modal dialog form I'm working on using Knockout.js, the "Submit" button triggers a method which should hide the dialog and then set the value of a variable.

```
self.updateSubTask = function(subTask) {
    ...
    $('#subTaskDialog').modal('hide');
    self.selectedSubTask(null);
};
```

When this function is called, the hide process begins - the dialog itself is removed - but is stopped before completion, and the grey background persists indefinitely. After some investigation, it is most likely that this is because the subsequent call to set the value of `self.selectedSubTask` is disrupting the hide "animation". Unfortunately, the modal call must be made before the change to `selectedSubTask` due to the way the dialog is set up. I've tried the following:

```
_.defer(function() { self.selectedSubTask(null); })
$('#subTaskDialog').queue(function() { self.selectedSubTask(null); });
```

Unfortunately, neither of these methods work, and the behaviour is the same.

I figure that a reasonable course of action would be to listen for when the dialog is hidden, and include the `selectedSubTask` call in that event handler. I'm having difficulty finding a solution to achieve this, however. Any suggestions on how to do this, or any other methods to achieve my ultimate aim, would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried the solutions in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22056147/bootstrap-modal-backdrop-remaining) or [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519660/twitter-bootstrap-modal-backdrop-doesnt-disappear) question?

Comment: I have, and unfortunately, neither helped. Cheers for the suggestions, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bind a function to the event in which the modal is hidden (this event is referred to as `hidden.bs.modal`):

```
self.updateSubTask = function(subTask) {
    $('#subTaskDialog').modal('hide');

    // capture the modal's "hidden" event
    $( "#subTaskDialog" ).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
        self.selectedSubTask(null);
    });
};
```

From the Bootstrap documentation on `hidden.bs.modal`:

> This event is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

There is also a `hide.bs.modal` event, in case that suits your desired functionality better. From the Bootstrap documentation:

> This event is fired immediately when the hide instance method has been called.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try it out when I get access to the code again tomorrow and let you know if it works.