# How to remove bootstrap modal overlay?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

How to remove bootstrap modal overlay for particular modal.
when modal appears background has black color with some opacity
is there any option for removing that elements...

Comment: removed based on what criteria? Can you show some code?

Answer (score 52):

Add `data-backdrop="false"` option as attribute to the button which opens the modal.

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-backdrop="false">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```

See [modal options](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options)

Comment: This has been updated in 5.3 to `data-bs-backdrop="false"`

Answer (score 14):

You can also set

```
.modal-backdrop {
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

in your css and bootstrap click outside function will still work.

Comment: Absolutely Brilliant.! Simple and sweet. Straight to the point without any fuzz.

Answer (score 12):

I was able to use the following snippet to hide the model overlay by just re-hiding the modal when the `shown.bs.modal` event is triggered.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#modal-id').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
      $(".modal-backdrop.in").hide();
   })
</script>
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also do it this way if you trigger you modal from javascript, add the **data-backdrop="false"** to the modal directly Example Below:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="notifyModal" data-backdrop="false"
tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content" id="info_content">
            A Project has been deleted successfully!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This has been updated in 5.3 to data-bs-backdrop="false"

Answer (score 7):

If you are dealing with bootstrap modal through jquery then better you use below code in your event callback function.

```
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you using function `click` in javascript (jquery). You using :

```
$("#myBtn2").click(function(){
    $("#myModal2").modal({backdrop: false});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The background is fired with the following class: `.modal-backdrop` with an additional `.in` class for opacity.

Default values (edit as needed):

```
.modal-backdrop {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1040;
    background-color: #000;
}
.modal-backdrop.in {
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: .5;
}
```

Comment: @Manigandaprabhu: 
`#modal-id .modal-backdrop {
     ...
 }`

Comment: in the given example, change `opacity: .5;` to `opacity: .0;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove()
});
```

This should work as a charm

Answer (score 0):

**This works for me. You may try this.**

$('.close').click();

$(document.body).removeClass("modal-open");

$("modal-backdrop").remove();

**https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/853**

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("div").removeClass("modal-backdrop");
  });
});
    </script>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29881176)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `backdropClass`, a custom class to append to the modal backdrop ([api)](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api).

**TS**

```
this.modalService.open(MyModalComponent, {
      backdrop: 'static',
      keyboard: false,
      backdropClass: 'no-backdrop'
});
```

**CSS** (global style)

```
.no-backdrop {
  background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and i solved it by removing the div with class modal-backdrop.
after the ajax success.

```
$.ajax({
         url: 'Your/URL',
         type: 'POST',
         data: formData, // Instance of FormData()
         contentType: false,
         processData: false,
         headers: {
             'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                   },
         success: function(response) {
              $('.modal-backdrop').remove()
              // Your code here, what you wanna do after the success of your ajax call
                  },
         error: function() {
               console.log('error');
                   },
         complete: function() {
                console.log('complete');
                   }
        })
```

I'm using : Bootstrap "version": "4.0.5".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found out that ii I simply used javascript to show and hide the modal form and remove the data-target attribute from the button that calls the modal, everything works fine. No need to remove data-backdrop and all of that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Add `data-bs-backdrop="false"` to modal attributes not the button that triggers the modal.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap 5.2.3**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="mobile-menu" class="modal fade" aria-labelledby="menuModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
   ....
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
const menuModal = new bootstrap.Modal('#mobile-menu', {
  backdrop: false
});
//show modal:
$(".book").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    menuModal.show();
});
```

**CSS:**

if you need only high opacity to backdrop apply this:

```
.modal-backdrop.show {
    --bs-backdrop-opacity: .1;
}
```