# modal greyed out on HTML

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

No matter what CSS or pure HTML modal I put onto my website it keeps getting completely grayed out when you click to open it . I first tried it in my nav bar and assumed maybe it has something to do with the z-index but literally wherever I put it it keeps getting grayed out when you click it. I'm Obviously not going to show the whole source code because it's too much but I just want to know what to look for.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
      Launch demo modal
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi David, you will need to post some [reprex] as  the HTML you posted runs just fine. There will be some CSS and JS that does the showing and 'greying' of the modal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `data-backdrop="false"` as an attribute to your code button.
Full code below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="false" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

More info click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459337/how-to-remove-bootstrap-modal-overlay) from Stack Overflow