# Bootstrap modal disappearing as soon as it loads but leaving the backdrop in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a bootstrap modal, it launches as soon as the page is loaded. It works fine in every browser except Safari. The modal will display for as long as a the fade animation then the modal box will disappear leaving only the backdrop and preventing the site from being used.

I've verified bootstrap is only being loaded once.

using bootstrap 3.1.1

Comment: @isherwood Besides that there isn't much. it's a basic modal being triggered via js and a cancel button. I could post the HTML but it's working in everything but Safari. But really the down vote? I have an actual problem I need help with.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle to verify this safari behaviour? Please tell us also the safari version.

Comment: @DirkLachowski Well. I made a fiddle using the same code: http://jsfiddle.net/capnmiddles/QxHB8/ and it works like a charm (of course) so there must be something else at work that's not playing nice with Safari. Thanks for the suggestion though, at least it rules bootstrap out (sort of).

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11544860/1686330

Comment: Matt, downvotes are not to be taken personally--they have nothing to do with how sincere you are. They're an indication that a question isn't likely to be helpful to other SO users. In this case, we don't have enough information to help you, such as anything at all about your code or the environment it's running in, and we can't see a demonstration of the problem. There's little of value in the question from a community perspective. Best of luck.

Comment: @isherwood I'm not apposed to a down-vote but there is no value in down-voting someone with out providing feedback. It's important to educate community users why something isn't providing value instead of quietly shunning them.

Comment: I did. I requested more detail in the form of HTML. You declined. Again, it's an assessment of the question's value to the community, not you personally. I don't "shun" people on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of completion there was another widget on the page that was conflicting with the bootstrap modal *only* on Safari.