# Bootstrap and problems with its modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a problem with bootstrap,
I included my modal with these lines of code (I use Jade):

```
<button data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary">Launch demo modal</button>
<div id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 id="myModalLabel" class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">...</div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I click the button it opens the modal, but when I should close the modal, it just close the modal and leave overlay! I really don't understand why it happens...

These are the screenshot before and after close the modal:

**BEFORE:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkcSe.jpg

**AFTER:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Uovr.jpg

---

According to you what is the problem?

ps: don't touch behind, it still doesn't work well :p

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519660/twitter-bootstrap-modal-backdrop-doesnt-disappear)

Comment: The code behaves correctly on it's own.  There must be other factors involved.