# Bootstrap modal background won't disappear

Tags: css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

So I have this *sign in* page using `Bootstrap`s `modal`. However after the call has finished the `modal` disappears as it should. Except for the black background. How can I make sure that the background disappears as well?

My _Menu.cshtml:

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="modal fade" id="form_login" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="form_LoginLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog reset">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
                </div>

                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SignIn", "Account", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "menu", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess="CloseModal()" }, new { @class = "form-inline", @role = "form" }))
                {
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        @if(ViewBag.Message != null)
                        {
                            <p class="alert alert-warning">@ViewBag.Message</p>
                        }

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" value="" required="required" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="password">Password</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" value="" required="required" />
                        </div>

                        <span id="message-login-loading" class="alert hidden"></span>
                        <span id="message-login-error" class="alert alert-danger hidden"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="login" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign in</button>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

AccountController:

```
    public ActionResult PartialMenu()
    {
        var model = ProfileSession.Session;
        return PartialView("_Menu", model);
    }

    public ActionResult SignIn(string email, string password)
    {
        Login login = loginRep.GetByEmailAndPassword(email, password);

        if (login != null)
        {
            ProfileSession.Session = profileRep.GetById(login.fk_profile);
            return RedirectToAction("PartialMenu", "Home");
        }

        ViewBag.Message("Email or password is incorrect");

        return RedirectToAction("PartialMenu");
    }
```

Comment: Create a jsfiddle please.  Also, "background"?  Do you mean the overlay/backdrop?  Your server code is irrelevant.

Comment: @im1dermike: I don't think the server code is irrelevant. Since the problem occours after I've called the server. And the code shows how the form should be updated.

What I don't understand is why the faded black background which is behind the white modal doesn't disappear together with the modal. And I'm unable to redo the problem in jsFiddle. Sorry

Comment: When I pop your modal code as it is into Bootply and pop it on page load, then dismiss it, it goes away normally: http://www.bootply.com/DkrP5BPYsA. Unless there's a way to replicate the error, I'm not sure how much help anyone is going to be able to give you.

Comment: @MattD: You are closing the modal with the "close" x in the top corner right? That works for me as well. It's after the ajax call that the problem occours. I thinks the problem occours due to the update that the aja does. What I'm wondering is if there is a way to maybe force the background to disappear if the ajax call was a success

Comment: You should be able to send a success message back to be handled via JavaScript. If it's a success, run `.modal('hide')` on your modal and that should hide it completely. Thing is, without a viable way to test or reproduce the issue, it's very unlikely that anyone here will be able to help you.

Comment: @MichaelTotKorsgaard: It's a client-side concern...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11544860/1021115) answer the problem is that my `Ajax` call updates my `div` and therefore the modal ain't visible. The backdrop is however, and its unable to connect to the modal and is therefore unable to disappear like it normally would.

I ended up using the

```
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

which on a succesfull ajax call, this removes all the backdrops on the page.

Please go and give Fre a vote up on his answer ^^

Comment: Warning: I found that since the modal backdrop removes the scroll bar when shown, this solution doesn't return the scroll bar to the window. In other words, you won't have a scroll bar until the page refreshes.

Comment: While the above answer works, the answers provided here http://stackoverflow.com/a/30373324/2630841 and here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20109519/2630841 are better.

Comment: This hides the modal but user need to click twice to open the modal after this code .... How to shoot this problem

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the  data-backdrop="false" property on your button.

Answer (score 0):

**This works of mine.**

$('.close').click();

$(document.body).removeClass("modal-open");

$("modal-backdrop").remove();

**https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/853**