# link opens but modal backdrop stays

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a SignIn button, which opens a modal in which I used ng-include to show another html page in that modal.
See the code below:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="loginpop" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div ng-include="'views/newlogin.html'"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now in "newlogin.html", I have a link as shown below:

```
<a href="/forgotpassword" onclick="$('#loginpop').modal('hide')">Forgot Password</a>
```

On clicking it,should redirect to /forgotpassword page,which is working correctly but the modal backdrop stays.
[You can see it here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDWnA.png)

I tried many solutions like

> data-dismiss="modal"

and also

> $('#loginpop').modal('hide')

none of them worked for me. Please provide something.

Thanks in advance.

I'm new to stackoverflow, so kindly overlook any discrepancies.

Comment: i think its a typo.. Shouldn it be `$("#loginpop").modal("hide")` rather than `$('#modalpop').modal('hide')` ?

Comment: yes, thanks for letting know, i just corrected it in question.

Comment: you mean to say the issue still is present ?

Comment: yes, it is. I'm still getting the backdrop.

Comment: When you click on the link, the modal code is removed and hence i hope bootstrap could not find a reference to it. This could be your solution. Try forcing it to close as he does. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519660/twitter-bootstrap-modal-backdrop-doesnt-disappear

Comment: Well, i tried those but, as you can see i am using _ng-include_ in my modal,  the script code doesn't work as it is inside the _newlogin.html_ .

Comment: In that case, try to declare a method in scope and call the required jQuery methods from the scope method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could finally use a script to solve the issue above.

I included:

```
$('#modal-clear').click(function(){
$('#loginpop').modal('toggle');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

the above script in the ***newlogin.html*** page where i have the links. I added `id=#modal-clear`to the */forgotpassword* link and boom!

Now its working.