# Bootstrap 4 close modal, backdrop doesn't disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am using boostrap 4 so I have

css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

js:

```
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

So I have modal and inside of it are checkboxes for product.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="smallmodalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body items-container products">
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col col-sm-6 pr-1">
                    <select data-placeholder="Choose Brand..." multiple class="standard-select mb-3">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="1">Brand 1</option>
                        <option value="1">Brand 2</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-sm-6 pl-0">
                    <input type="text" id="search_by_name" placeholder="Search by Name" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="product_checkboxes" style="margin-top: 45px;position:relative;">
                <div class="partial-loader hide"></div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label class="checkbox-bootstrap checkbox-lg">                           
                        <input type="checkbox" class="product-checkbox" name="product" value="1">             
                        <span class="checkbox-placeholder"></span>           
                        Sample Item
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label class="checkbox-bootstrap checkbox-lg">                           
                        <input type="checkbox" class="product-checkbox" name="product" value="2">             
                        <span class="checkbox-placeholder"></span>           
                        Sample Item 2
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add_selected_button" disabled>Add Selected Products</button><img class="hide loader" src="/logo/loader.gif" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On my Js file I have event for add_selected_button

```
$(modalJs.addSelectedButtonSelector).click(function() {
    var me = $(this);

    me.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $(modalJs.chosenSelector).prop('disabled', true).trigger("chosen:updated");
    $(modalJs.inputSearchTextSelector).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.btn-secondary').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    var selectedId = [];
    $(modalJs.productCheckboxesSelector +' input:checked').each(function() {
        selectedId.push(parseInt($(this).val()));
    });

    var loader = $('.products .partial-loader');
    loader.removeClass(core.common.classToHideElement);
    $('img.loader').show();

    var csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content");
    var store = $.ajax({
        url: "/product/store",
        type: "PUT",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            product_ids: selectedId, 
            _csrf : csrfToken
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $('#modal').modal('hide');
        },
    });
});
```

I am trying to hide the modal manually after ajax request done and successful.
according to their [website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) just put this code

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide')
```

It close the modal, however the backdrop doesn't disappear.

I try to do this

```
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

Base [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519660/twitter-bootstrap-modal-backdrop-doesnt-disappear)

It works, backdrop is disappear, **however the button to show the modal is not working anymore unless I refresh the page**.

The button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary ml-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">
    <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    Add Products
</button>
```

Any help? thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried this, but instead of removing the backdrop, try hiding it: `$('.modal-backdrop').hide();`.

Comment: @Nisarg Still button not working anymore after modal closed.

Comment: What is modalJS ?, could you reproduce that in a test area like fiddle or something like that ?

Comment: I just created an object to store properties and method the value of modalJs.addSelectedButtonSelector is "#add_selected_button"

Comment: I tried to create codepen. But it seem work https://codepen.io/titan_dl_1904/pen/ELvWRJ

Answer (score 6):

BS also adds a class to the <body> element that needs to be removed (see [this thread](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/853)). Try this code:

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
$(document.body).removeClass('modal-open');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

Comment: Can someone tell why I have to implement this manually? The code must be there in bootstrap because I can close the Modal with the data-dismiss attribute properly.

Answer (score 4):

I found that making the code from @JohnRiehl into a function made things easier for multiple modals (using this once in the code works for all modals and no duplication of code):

```
$(".modal").on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(document.body).removeClass('modal-open');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
});
```