# Modal window blocks my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal window but when I close the modal my page is blocked. I can not do anything. I need to refresh the page to get everything working again!
The strange is that sometimes everything works well or sometimes everything is blocked!

The button that opens the model:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalCode">Approve</button>
```

My modal window code:

```
<!-- Modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalCode" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form id="formUpdateProgress" >
                {!! csrf_field() !!}
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Complaint Progress</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <label class="control-label">Insert code:</label>
                    <div id='complaintProgress' style="position: relative;">
                        <input type="text" name="code" id="code" placeholder="Insert the code here">
                    </div>                   
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">                              
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END MODAL -->
```

When I submit the form, I close the model!

```
$( '#formUpdateProgress' ).on( 'submit', function(e) {
    $('#myModalCode').modal('hide');
});
```

EXAMPLE:

Modal window in my application:
[image: Modal window example]

Then I click Submit, everything works ok, the document is approved but something is locking the page:
[image: After submit everything is blocked]

**Any idea why the page is blocked?** Thanks in advance

Comment: That transparent black is probably a div that you do not remove with the modal.

Comment: The whole point of a **modal** window is that it blocks other activity. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar issues is discussed in here:

[How to hide Bootstrap modal from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466129/how-to-hide-bootstrap-modal-from-javascript)

Seems that you have some issues in the way how your modal is handling the submit. Perhaps the easiest fix would be as was mentioned in one of the comments from the link above, add the following fix to remove the backdrop:

```
$('.modal-backdrop').hide();
```

Alternatively, you may even remove() it. I'd think, modal will re-create it again, if open.

Answer (score 1):

It's looks like you are using [bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals). 
Bootstrap open not only modal, but page mask too. So you need to call bootstrap method to close. With code inspector you can find that body got class="modal-open" and extra div with "modal-backdrop fade in"

Just use `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>` or yr element with 'data-dismiss="modal"' and all be ok)

Comment: thanks for the answer but I was really missing this: $('.modal-backdrop').hide();

Answer (score 0):

```
    function closeModal(name){
         $("#"+name).modal('hide');
         // I added the next line
         $('.modal-backdrop').hide();
    }
```

After I add the $('.modal-backdrop').hide(); everything its ok :)