# Get/import bootstrap.js from Webpack bundle.js

Tags: javascript, webpack

Sorry i not have experience with webpack.

I have a template page generated with Webpack.

The page show modal dialog with bootstrap.js

The bootstrap.js included in bundle.js

I need show/hide/listen event of modal windows but i can not use 
$('#dialog').modal('hide') because bootstrap not loaded (in current context?)

**How i can import/get access to bootstrap.js in bundle.js?**

```
Examples - try to close modal with button "Close with JS"
```

[Sample #1 used bootstrap.js from bundle.js](https://codepen.io/AlexandrM/pen/QzJqgz)

**Error**

> $(...).modal is not a function

[Sample #2 used bootstrap.js from bundle.js and in html](https://codepen.io/AlexandrM/pen/xmQXYE)

**Error**

> not removed modal-backdrop fade

Importing settings

[image]

Comment: How did you include bootstrap into your project? You can simple `import 'bootstrap';` at `index.js` or `app.js`.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov https://codepen.io/AlexandrM/pen/QzJqgz without including bootsrap.js https://codepen.io/AlexandrM/pen/xmQXYE with including bootsrap.js

Comment: @AlexandrSulimov could you show us your html and js code?

Comment: @MM Yes, samples in question. https://codepen.io/AlexandrM/pen/QzJqgz without including bootsrap.js https://codepen.io/AlexandrM/pen/xmQXYE with including bootsrap.js

Comment: @AlexandrSulimov I had seen the codepen samples. By html/js code, I meant the complete code, including the part where you have imported bootstrap whether through downloading the library or through cdn. I could not find any mention of bootstrap in the codepen links. Pardon me but I am not sure on how codepen imports work.

Comment: @M M  In codepen is minimal project with bug. I have add a screen shot where is visible importing. There are to links/projects 1) not used external bootsrap.js (i can not hide modal by .modal('hide') 2) used external bootsrap.js (modal not closed fully, "backdrop" not hide)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just inspect your codepen example and somehow 2 modal-backdrop generated on the two of your example. (with or without bootstrap)

[image]

and one of them remain on the page when the other one closed.

I just check if there is some bug or anything else on the bootsrap and face with closed issue on the github;

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/679

Somehow, some of the people face with your problem too and caused by many issue.

You may delete the second backdrop manually on the your with bootstrap example for the short cut solution.

**Update:**

After the Alexandr Sulimov's feedback, I just re-search it again and find that a topic on stackoverflow with the similar issue;

[How to hide Bootstrap modal from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466129/how-to-hide-bootstrap-modal-from-javascript)

I test it on the with bootstrap codepen example and works very well

```
$("[data-dismiss=modal]").trigger({ type: "click" });
```

@Alexandr, can you try your code as below that as I understand just mimic the close with TAG;

```
$(function(){
   $('#closeWithJS').on('click', function(){
       $("[data-dismiss=modal]").trigger({ type: "click" });
   });
});
```

Comment: When i have removed second backdrop - modal dialog not shown by button "Open modal for @mdo" https://clip2net.com/s/3Zd6xT8

Comment: @AlexandrSulimov I update my answer upon your feedback

Comment: Thanks, yes it solution is works. If will not answers in 2 day i mark you answer as answer with bounty. I seek an answer to a question "How i can import/get access to bootstrap.js in bundle.js?" because i want use a usual code ".modal('hide')" and one instance of bootstrap.js

Comment: Let me know, did you add your bootstrap.js script file in the index.html's header manually? If yes, you may guide : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/

Comment: Or this might helps to you; https://medium.com/commencis/how-to-import-bootstrap-using-webpack-7245eba98056

Comment: I have a bundle.js (are includes a bootsrap.js compiled/minified with webpack) + html page. I need run code  $('#M').modal('hide') (in <script> section or console). It not work because bootsrap.js not available. If i include second copy of bootsrap.js  in header - $('#M').modal('hide') works not correctly. I think, there is a way to use bootsrap.js from bundle.js

Comment: From the official bootstrap 's docs; Bootstrap is dependent on jQuery and Popper, these are defined as peerDependencies, this means that you will have to make sure to add both of them to your package.json. Are these two files included in to your project too?